# Python pandas - new column based on other columns (String)

Tags: python, pandas

I couldn't find it in stackoverflow, so I wanted to ask the question.

Let's assume that i have two columns: A, B in data frame, which consist of just a bunch of words, and i want to create a new column C which is just TRUE/FALSE based on the following rule:

```
 If word in B = word in A + 'ing', then it's True or vice versa
 If word in B = word in A + 'ment', then it's True of vice versa.
```

so I defined the following function:

```
def parts_of_speech(s1, s2):
    return s1+'ing'==s2 or s1+'ment'==s2 or s1+s1[-1]+'ing'==s2
```

For instance

```
  A              B            C
Engage         Engagement   True
Go             Going        True
Axe            Axis         False
Management     Manage       True
```

I tried the following:

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x: parts_of_speech(x.A, x.B) or 
                           parts_of_speech(x.B, x.A) )
```

or

```
df['C']=df.apply(parts_of_speech(df['A'], df['B']) or 
                           parts_of_speech(df['A'], df['B']) )
```

I get the same error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I don't know what i did incorrectly. Is there an easy fix for this?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `s1+s1[-1]+'ing'==s2` is not correct.  You will get something like `Manageeing`.  Use `s1[:-1] + 'ing'` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.apply works with columns by default. The only change needed in your example is to add `axis=1` to apply to rows:

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x: parts_of_speech(x.A, x.B) or parts_of_speech(x.B, x.A),
                 axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data:

```
# make B the longer words
df[['A','B']] = np.sort(df[['A','B']])

# split by suffixes
df['B'].str.extract('(\w+)(ment|ing)$',expand=True)[0].eq(df['A'])
```

Or use your approach, but vectorized:

```
# make B the longer words
df[['A','B']] = np.sort(df[['A','B']])

df['A-ing'] = df['A'] + 'ing'
df['A-ment'] = df['A'] + 'ment'

df.iloc[:,-2].eq(df['A']).all(1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: There are some more complex cases, like `hop + ing = hopping`. I guess the question is not about the language processing part

Comment: Sure, but then it's about the logic, and your answer doesn't work as well.

Comment: > I guess the question is not about the language processing part